# bottle.py python, download file with previous entered filename?

Tags: python, bottle

i try to build a simple userinterface with a raspberry and bottle.py.
in one step the User can create a new File and name it:

```
<form action="/ziel" method="post">
Dateiname eingeben:<input name="filename" type="text" />
</form>
```

i create the file with the filename the user gave it:

```
filename = request.forms.get('filename')
test_file = open(filename +".txt","w")
```

now my question: i want to create a page where the user can download the file. how can i request the filename the user entered and put it in the download link?

```
@route('/download')
def download():
return '''

<a href="static/"what to put here???".txt">Download Txt</a>
'''
```

thanks for your answers!

Comment: Check 'Forced Download' here: http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html. Is that what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by saving the name in a session using https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bottle-session/0.4
then destroy the session after providing a download link.